# Вывод пути, через алгоритм Дейкстры

Tags: c#, поиск-пути

В общем и целом, сам алгоритм у меня реализован и находит кратчайший путь(все пути указаны в матрицы смежности), но не сохраняет дорогу. Как можно это реализовать еще на этапе прохождения моего алгоритма?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

#region Задание

/* Нахождение кратчайшего пути мнжду вершинами графа(заданного через матрицу смежности)
при помощи алгооритма Дейкстры (матрица смежности считывается из файла) */

#endregion


namespace _1lab
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Данные матрицы

            var path = @"D:\massiv.txt"; //путь
            var sizeOfMatrix = File.ReadAllLines(path); //Считывание всех строк из файла
            var matrix = new int[sizeOfMatrix.Length, sizeOfMatrix[0].Split(' ').Length]; //Инициализация двумерного массива
            matrix = FillingMatrix(sizeOfMatrix, matrix); //Заполнение матрицы смежности
            var matrixSize = sizeOfMatrix.Length; //Размер матрицы

            #endregion
            
            var findSpt = new ShortestPathFinder(matrix, matrixSize);
            
            findSpt.MatrixPrint(); //Вывод матрицы смежности
            
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", findSpt.Dijkstra(matrix, 0)));

            var abc = findSpt.Dijkstra(matrix, 0);


        }


        #region Заполнение матрицы смежности

        static int[,] FillingMatrix(string[] sizeOfMatrix, int[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfMatrix.Length; i++)
            {
                var temp = sizeOfMatrix[i].Split(' ');
                for (int j = 0; j < temp.Length; j++)
                    try
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(temp[j]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("в вашей матрице есть неверные типы данных");
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
            }

            return matrix;
        }
        
        

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Сама Дейкстра

```
using System;

namespace _1lab
{
    public class ShortestPathFinder
    {
        public ShortestPathFinder(int[,] matrix, int matrixSize) //Конструктор (передаем все внешние даннные в класс ShortestPathFinder)
        {
            Matrix = matrix;
            MatrixSize = matrixSize;
        }

        private int[,] Matrix { get; }
        private int MatrixSize { get; }

        public void MatrixPrint()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ваша исходная матрица : ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", Matrix[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        private int MinDistance(int[] dist, bool[] sptSet)
        {
            var min = int.MaxValue;
            var minIndex = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
            {
                if (sptSet[i] == false && dist[i] <= min)
                {
                    min = dist[i];
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }

            return minIndex;
        }
        public int[] Dijkstra(int[,] matrix, int root)
        {
            var dist = new int[MatrixSize];

            var checkPoint = new bool[MatrixSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++) //Заполняем масив кратчайших путей и посещенных точек
            {
                dist[i] = int.MaxValue;
                checkPoint[i] = false;
            }

            dist[root] = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize - 1; i++)
            {

                var minDist = MinDistance(dist, checkPoint);

                checkPoint[minDist] = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < MatrixSize; j++)

                    if (!checkPoint[j] && matrix[minDist, j] != 0 && dist[minDist] != int.MaxValue && dist[minDist] + matrix[minDist, j] < dist[j])
                        dist[j] = dist[minDist] + matrix[minDist, j];
            }

            return dist;

        }

        
    }
}
```

Данные которые в файле хранятся:

```
0 10 30 50 10
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 10
0 40 20 0 0
10 0 10 30 0
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_dijkstra Ищите "восстановление путей"

Answer (score 1):

В общем и целом. Разобрался с статье и написал такой код. На примерах работает хорошо

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _1lab
{
    public class ShortestPathFinder
    {
        
        public ShortestPathFinder(int[,] matrix, int matrixSize) //Конструктор (передаем все внешние даннные в класс ShortestPathFinder)
        {
            Matrix = matrix;
            MatrixSize = matrixSize;
        }
        private int[,] Matrix { get; } 
        private int MatrixSize { get; }
        
        
        
        
        public void MatrixPrint()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ваша исходная матрица : ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", Matrix[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        private int MinDistance(int[] dist, bool[] sptSet)
        {
            var min = int.MaxValue;
            var minIndex = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
            {
                if (sptSet[i] == false && dist[i] <= min)
                {
                    min = dist[i];
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }

            return minIndex;
        } 
        public void Dijkstra(int[,] matrix, int root)
        {
            var dist = new int[MatrixSize];

            var path = new int[MatrixSize];

            var checkPoint = new bool[MatrixSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++) //Заполняем масив кратчайших путей и посещенных точек
            {
                dist[i] = int.MaxValue;
                checkPoint[i] = false;
            }

            dist[root] = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize - 1; i++)
            {
                var minDist = MinDistance(dist, checkPoint);

                checkPoint[minDist] = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < MatrixSize; j++)
                {
                    if (!checkPoint[j] && matrix[minDist, j] != 0 && dist[minDist] != int.MaxValue && dist[minDist] + matrix[minDist, j] < dist[j])
                    {
                        dist[j] = dist[minDist] + matrix[minDist, j];
                        path[j] = minDist; //Заполняется массив предков
                    }
                }
            }

            

            Console.WriteLine("Данные о путях(по Дейкстре):");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Наша начальная точка 1");
            
            for (int i = 1; i < MatrixSize; i++)
            {
                if (path[i] == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Кратчайший путь: из 1 -> {i + 1} прямой | Мин.Расстояние: {dist[i]}");
                else
                {
                    var stack = new Stack<int>(); //Используем стэк для сохранения пути. Так как мы идем в обратном порядке, путь по итогу должен выводиться перевернтный
                    stack.Push(path[i] + 1);
                    
                    Console.Write($"Кратчайший путь: из 1 -> ");

                    for (int j = path[i]; j != 0; j = path[j])
                    {
                        if (path[j] == 0)
                            break;
                        else
                        {
                            stack.Push(path[j]);
                            j = path[j];
                        }
                        
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j <= stack.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == stack.Count)
                            Console.Write($"{i + 1} | Мин.Расстояние: {dist[i]}");
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write(stack.Pop() + " -> ");
                            j = -1;
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```